# "Суффикс" инфинитива

Tags: морфемика

В инфинитивах разных глаголов между глагольной основой и показателем *ть/ти* стоят разные гласные — интерфиксы, которые принято обозначать как суффиксы. (Верно ли это утверждение?)

Рассмотрим, к примеру, такие глаголы: ход**и**ть, пад**а**ть, се**я**ть. Чем обусловлено наличие именно *а*, а не, например, *я*  или *и* перед *ть* в глаголе *падать*? Есть какая-то закономерность?

Answer (score 1):

Гласный перед суффиксом инфинитива  -ть может быть безударным. Для определения того, какую букву следует писать на месте этого безударного гласного, используется понятие усекаемости глагольной основы. Усекаемыми являются основы глаголов, в которых гласный, находящийся в инфинитиве перед -ть , отсутствует в формах настоящего будущего времени, напр.: курить – курю, курят; видеть – вижу, видишь, видят; стоять – стою, стоит; махнуть – махнёт, махнём.

Неусекаемыми являются основы глаголов, в которых этот гласный в формах настоящего будущего времени сохраняется, напр.: читать – читаю, читают; гулять – гуляешь, гуляет; белеть – белеет, белеют; гнить – гниёт, гниют.

Написание букв на месте безударных гласных перед суффиксом -ть инфинитива определяется следующим правилом.

1. После мягких парных согласных (т. е. не после шипящих) в глаголах с усекаемой основой перед -ть пишется буква и, а в глаголах с неусекаемой основой – е , напр.: верить (ср. верю, верят), править (правлю, правят), гладить (глажу, гладят), встретить (встречу, встретят), но обезлюдеть (обезлюдеет), посолиднеть (посолиднеет).

Исключения: глаголы с усекаемой основой видеть, зависеть, ненавидеть и обидеть (ср. видят, зависят, ненавидят, обидят), в которых не пишется буква и , а пишется е , и глагол с неусекаемой основой кашлять (ср. кашляю ), в котором не пишется буква е , а пишется я .

2. После шипящих согласных в глаголах с усекаемой основой перед -ть пишется буква и , а в глаголах с неусекаемой основой – буквы а или е , напр.: наскучить (ср. наскучу, наскучат),умножить (умножу, умножат), утешить (утешу, утешат), таращить (таращу, таращат), но: вешать (ср. вешает, вешают), скушать (скушает, скушают), сплетничать(сплетничают), обезматочеть (обезматочеет ), оравнодушеть (оравнодушеет ), ополоуметь (ополоумеют). Исключение: глагол слышать с усекаемой основой (ср. слышу), в котором не пишется буква и, а пишется а.

Примечание 1 к пп. 1 и 2. О разграничении глаголов I спряжения на -еть (с неусекаемой основой) типа обессилеть, обездушеть и глаголов II спряжения на -ить (с усекаемой основой) типа обессилить, обездушить. В разговорной речи у некоторых глаголов на -еть с неусекаемой основой (выздороветь, выздоровею, выздоровеет; опостылеть, опостылеет; опротиветь, опротивеют ) имеются вариантные формы, образованные по «усекаемому» типу, которые передаются на письме с окончаниями II спряжения: выздоровлю, выздоровит, выздоровят, опостылю, опостылит, опротивят и т. п.

Примечание 2 к пп. 1 и 2. В глаголах мерить и мучить (и в производных от них глаголах), имеющих, кроме личных форм типа мерю, меришь, мерят, мучу, мучишь, мучат , допустимые вариантные формы типа меряю, меряешь, меряют, мучаю, мучаешь, мучают , в инфинитиве перед -ть и в формах, сохраняющих основу инфинитива, пишется только буква и : мерил, отмерив, замучила и т. п. (такие написания, как мерять, мерял, мучать, мучал, отмеряв, замучавшись , не соответствуют современной орфографической норме).

3. После гласных (встречающихся только в глаголах с усекаемой основой) перед -ть пишутся буквы и или я . Буква и пишется после гласного о, напр.: стоить, строить, успокоить ; буква я после гласных а, е, у, напр.: лаять (ср. лает), таять, каяться, веять, надеяться, лелеять, сеять, затеять, чуять. Исключения: глаголы драить и клеить, где после гласных а и е не пишется буква я, а пишется и.

Answer (score 0):

Это исторически обусловленные случаи отнесения к разным спряжениям.
Вообще в общеславянском на этапе его разделения, а потом и в восточнославянской общности существовало несколько типов спряжения (по Хабургаеву - 7, плюс "неправильные"). 
Следы этого можно наблюдать даже на уровне школьной программы - в обилии всякого рода исключений (все эти гнать, брить и ненавидеть) и разноспрягаемых глаголов. 
Поднимать всё это - слишком муторно и неформатно для ресурса.
Достаточно вспомнить уже то, что инфинитив исторически не был исходной формой глагола (это всего лишь закостеневшая форма особого дательного падежа), чтобы понять, сколько потребуется времени и сил, чтобы изложить хотя бы приблизительно всю схему.

Comment: Но ведь эти самые *а*, *я* и т. д. -- инфиксы, верно? Или показатели спряжений?

Comment: Ну наверное и то, и то. Одно другому не мешает. Я не сторонник терминологических дискуссий, хоть горшком назовите, сути это не раскроет..

Comment: Я имел в виду, конечно, ИНТЕРфиксы, а не инфиксы. Прошу прощения.

Comment: Я даже не обратил внимания.

Comment: Это не показатели спряжений, скорее, они зависят от спряжений. В широком смысле эти гласные называют интерфиксами в том смысле, что они соединяют основу слова и суффикс ть, Но не все учёные так считают, многие к интерфиксам относят только соединит. гласные в сложных словах.  http://flatik.ru/morfema-morfema